# Lodash - Filter based on whether array contains value, then map and join as comma separate string within Angular HTML template

Tags: angular, lodash

Using lodash within the HTML markup of an Angular application I need to filter based on whether an array contains a value, then map to get one of the properties and join the results as a comma separated string.

This is the JSON for the "attribute":

```
 {
        "ValueIntArray": [ 14, 15 ],
        "Options": [
          {
            "Id": 13,
            "Name": "Opt A"
          },
          {
            "Id": 14,
            "Name": "Opt B"
          },
          {
            "Id": 15,
            "Name": "Opt C"
          }
        ]
      }
```

So based on this the result I want to see is: "Opt B, Opt C"

However I am getting the following error:

> Parser Error: Bindings cannot contain assignments

This is the code I am trying to use to acheive this, if I remove the "filter" part then it displays a comma separated list of all the options so I know that part works therefore it is just the "filter" part that is causing a problem.

```
{{lodash(attribute.Options).filter(o => lodash.includes(attribute.ValueIntArray, o.Id)).map('Name').join(', ')}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue using the following:

```
{{lodash(attribute.Options).keyBy('Id').at(attribute.ValueIntArray).map('Name').join(', ')
```